# Html Encoding: weird character appears after UTF8 encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding, html-encode

I extracted content using NReadability (C#)

Original:

```
No worries with the team from IUOHA’s, you’ll find specific information about
```

Extracted content:

```
â€œNo worries with the team from IUOHAâ€™sâ€, you’ll findÂ specificÂ information about
```

I used Encoding.UTF8 and I get the following

```
No worries with the team from IUOHA’s, you�ll find specific information about
```

Any idea why the weird � appears instead of "’"?

Thanks

Comment: are you using the same encoding for encode and decode?

Comment: This is a Garbage In Garbage Out problem.  The single quote in "you’ll" should have been encoded as â€™ like it was in "IUOHA’s".  But it wasn't, it is still U+2019, so there is no way that you can avoid the � substitution character when the UTF8 decoder encounters the invalid bytes.  You'll need to file a bug report with whatever company or programmer that generated the text.